# How to run set of request before every request in Postman

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I'm writing test in Postman and I have multiple requests grouped like this:

1. Some test title:

   - Create a user (set of "pre-requests"):

     - sending a few requests required to create a user, necessary to run tests
   - Some action on a created user (here I'm testing what is in the test title)

     - one or more requests
2. Another test title:

   - Create a user (set of "pre-requests", the same as in test 1.):

     - sending a few requests required to create a user, necessary to run tests
   - Some action on a created user (not related ot test 1.)

     - one or more requests

To summarize I need to create a user before every request when I want to test something.

My question - How can I re-use "Create a user" set of requests without copying it?

Comment: Is this user always the same?

Comment: I have to create a new user every time to test the flow.

Comment: Yes but is the user object always the same? i.e. same name, id, etc. Also does it need to execute for every request or just at the beginning of the collection?

Comment: Every time I create a new user with different name: user_name_prefix + incremented number. User has to be created before set of request. e.g. 1) Create a user, 2) add some rights

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can re-use the set of requests in pre-testcases and Test by setting environment variable and call it using eval function

pre-test case -

```
var Create_a_user = () => {
pm.sendRequest("http://mocktarget.apigee.net/json", function(err, res) {

    tests["Status code is 200"] = pm.expect(res).to.have.property('code', 200);
    console.log('firstName',res.json().firstName);      
});

pm.sendRequest("http://mocktarget.apigee.net/json", function(err, res) {

    tests["Status code is 200"] = pm.expect(res).to.have.property('code', 200);
    console.log("lastName - "+ res.json().lastName);
});

pm.sendRequest("http://mocktarget.apigee.net/json", function(err, res) {

    tests["Status code is 200"] = res.code === 200;
    console.log("city - "+ res.json().lastName.city);
});
};

pm.environment.set("Create_a_user", Create_a_user.toString());
```

Test -

```
eval(pm.environment.get("Create_a_user"))();
```

output -

```
firstName - John

lastName - Doe

city - San Jose
```

Disclaimer - 
Use Eval function carefully, it may fizzled up your code or its execution.

Comment: Thanks for answear! I'm already using eval() function to reuse my code. My assumption is to have one request per one test step. Some of requests have pre-requests scripts and all of them have tests executed after request. So it's  more complex. I was rather thinking of reusing request in th collection runner, but postman.setNextRequest() doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: well you have completely changed the question now, see the question, you have not mention anything that you mentioned in comment, if you are already using eval function you should have mentioned that in question itself and you have not mentioned `reusing request in collection runner` before

Comment: Maybe you are right. My question is how to reuse whole request with prerequest and tests executed after request.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding correctly what you want is unfortunately not currently supported. I've been waiting on this feature a while myself.

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1535